# Trying to Set the Index of a td in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

In the process of creating a tile-swap puzzle game for my jQuery class. Right now I'm working on trying to make the clicked tile switch with the blank tile (I'll figure out how to limit it to adjacent tiles afterwards). I've stored indexes of both indexes in new variables, but I can't figure out how to assign a variable as the td elements index.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('img').click(function(){
    var tileSelected = $(this);            //grab the clicked tiles index
    var tileIndexOld = $("img").index(tileSelected);

    var blankTile = $("#blank");             //grab the blank tiles index
    var blankIndexOld = $("img").index(blankTile);

    var tileIndexNew = blankIndexOld;       //swap tile and blank indexes
    var blankIndexNew = tileIndexOld;

    $(this).attr("index", tileIndexNew);
    $("#blank").attr("index", blankIndexNew);
});
});
```

I've also tried doing things like $(tileSelected).index(tileIndexNew); and $(this).index() = tileIndexNew; etc. I just can't seem to figure out how to overwrite with the new index.

Edit:
Okay, I've been shown the wickedness of my (attempted) index swapping ways! Still working on the solution, but I'm changing tracks and focusing on altering the src's as suggested by Starscream1984. I'll update again once I've got it figured out, many thanks to all!

Solution: 
After trying it three different ways (with multiple sub-variations) this is what I ended up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("td").click( function(){

    var tileVertical = $(this).index();                 //get clicked tiles vertical position via its td
    var tileHorizontal = $(this).parent().index();      //get clicked tiles horizontal position via its tr

    var blankTile = $("#blank").parent();               //getting the td that contains the blank tile
    var blankVertical = blankTile.index();              //get blank tiles vertical position (via its td)
    var blankHorizontal = blankTile.parent().index();       //get blank tiles horizontal position via its tr

    if( Math.abs(blankVertical - tileVertical) + Math.abs(blankHorizontal - tileHorizontal) == 1)   //check if clicked tile is adjacent to the blank tile
        {
        blankTile.empty().html( $(this).html() );       //put the tile html into the blank slot
        $(this).html("<img id='blank' src='blank.jpeg' width='200px' />");          //fill the tile slot with the blank, ID IS CRITICAL!!!!
        }                                                                           //function will only run once if id is omitted from this tag!!!

    return 1;
});
});
```

My original approach tried to use the index as a quick and dirty variable to swap out. What I discovered was that the index in this case is simply more like a map with x and y coordinates. It was the inner html of the table cell that needed to be swapped, not the index itself.

Comment: `index` is not for setting the index of DOM elements but for filtering a set of selections by DOM index. see [jQuery index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: does your code work ? what errors are you getting?and if you just want to swap the selected tile with blank tile you can simply use `toggleClass()` or `removeClass()` and `addClass()`

Comment: You'd probably be better off switching the image source of your tiles, you can't set index like that.

Comment: Doesn't give me any errors, just simply doesn't work. and I get that index() is for retrieval but surely there has to be some way to change the index of an element?

Comment: You don't change the index of an element, you move it using something like `appendTo`.

Comment: What a good opportunity for you to learn! :) [**.index() | jQuery API Documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the elements around using jQuery DOM modification methods. This solution assumes that each tile is contained in a DIV in the grid.

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var tileSelected = $(this);
    var parentSelected = tileSelected.parent();
    var blankTile = $("#blank");
    var blankParent = blankTile.parent();

    parentSelected.append(blankTile);
    blankParent.append(tileSelected);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A)

```
$('img').each(function(index, elem){
  console.log(index);
});
```

B)

```
$('img').click(function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  //or
  //var index = $('img').index($(this));
  console.log(index);
});
```

Are the right ways. So your code seems to be correct. Are you sure that all imgages exists at the moment you run the function? Do you noticed that your selector find **all** img in DOM?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign an index variable for the td, one approach to do it dinamically is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tdArray = $("td");//grabs all td elements

    for(i = 0; i < tdArray.length; i++){
        $(tdArray[i]).attr('data-index',i);//adds a data-index attribute on each one 
    }
});
```

You could then handle a click event like this:

```
 $("td").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('data-index'));
 });
```

To keep track of your blank tile, you could simple assign its data-index to a global variable.